# How to get JS Intellisence working in VSCode with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have a clean install of VSCode on Windows 10. I am currently working on setting up the ENV for React development however, JS Intellisence is not working at all within the app folder created by `create-react-app`. When I open up a JS file and start typing, the following sign is infinitely looping without stopping.
[image]

Comment: What extension are you using for your JS files?

Comment: @EdLucas TSLint, Prettier, TS&JS Language Features

Comment: To clarify, what file extension are you using for your JS files (.js, .jsx, .ts, .jsx, etc)?

Comment: .js extension is used

Comment: @EdLucas it seems that there is a problem related to `yarn` or `create-react-app` cuz it's not working only inside the app folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is weird, I have just disabled the built-in feature `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` then, JS Intellisence is back to work again!

Seems a bug https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87658